# Convert.ToDateTime "string was not recognized as a valid datetime" error

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I am trying to get just the date portion from a datetime variable.

Reading the [documentation for currentculture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),  I tried with:

```
currentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(currentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
currentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(currentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

Convert.ToDateTime(myDT.ToShortDateString(), System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

But I got an "..not recognized as a valid datetime string" exception.

My question is, If I am setting a specific currentculture (in this case "es-MX") , How is possible the Parse() method is failing??? What I am missing?

I can solve the problem doing a myDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"). But I want to understand this behavior.

[See this image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/luferogoonline/8342329081/) , is the screenshot with my watch window. Again, my question is not about how to get the date portion, is about WHY I am getting the exception. Thank you!

Comment: You Can solve it by doing myDT.Date.

Comment: Post Your Exception with datetime variable as said by oded..

Comment: The first arg of Convert.ToDateTime() expects a date. ToShortDateString() outputs a string. Yes, you could format it to a string first, and then back to a date, but as @RuneFS and now Oded said, just use .Date

Comment: So is currentThread.CurrentUICulture  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture ????

Comment: @RuneFS Please read my question again... I am NOT asking how to get just the date portion.. I am asking how is possible that lines are throwing the  exception, taking in account I am setting the currentculture before. Thank you!

Comment: @TonyHopkinson : Yes, it is...

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to get just the date portion from a datetime variable.

```
myDateTime.Date
```

As [@Rune FS commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144632/convert-todatetime-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-error#comment19588306_14144632).

The property is defined on the `DateTime` structure - there is absolutely no need to convert to a string and back.

Comment: I know that also solves my problem. But that is not my question. My question is how is possible the parse to string and the cast to datetime again is failing, taking in account I am setting the culture... thank you

Comment: @Luferogo - What does `ToShortDateString()` give back? `Convert.ToDateTime` seems to fail on that.

Comment: the output is "03/mar/2013". The curious thing is with any other month is running fine...!. By example "01/ene/2013" runs fine.. I think is something related with the culture.

Comment: @Luferogo - That is strange, though using `dd/MMM/yyyy` with `ParseExact` will result in the correct `DateTime`.

Comment: Please see this image link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/luferogoonline/8342329081/ , is the screenshot of my watch window...I don not understand this at all! :S